# Fail to start systemd-journal

Tags: systemd, boot, systemd-journald

i have upgraded my linux rescently (apt-get upgrade) and now it can not boot successfully.
The booting process stop at a middle and ask for root authentification to resolve the issue
the log said systemd-journald fail to start but i don't understand why

```
# systemctl --failed
  UNIT                            LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DESCRIPTION
● systemd-journald.service        loaded failed failed Journal Service
● systemd-journald-audit.socket   loaded failed failed Journal Audit Socket
● systemd-journald-dev-log.socket loaded failed failed Journal Socket (/dev/log)
● systemd-journald.socket         loaded failed failed Journal Socket


# systemctl status systemd-journald.service
● systemd-journald.service - Journal Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-14 11:35:57 CET; 27s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
           man:journald.conf(5)
  Process: 2813 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journald (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
 Main PID: 2813 (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)


# systemctl start systemd-journald.service
Job for systemd-journald.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status systemd-journald.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


#journalctl -xe 
-- No entries --
```

if anyone has a clue ...

thank you

Comment: i found that adding "PrivateDevices=no
NoNewPrivileges=no" into /lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service allows to continue the boot.